# Disable Multiple login at Keycloak

Tags: authentication, keycloak

It is possible to disable multiple login at Keycloak?

Example:

I logged in on my browser at my PC and I do a login on my mobile phone... at this moment, keycloak invalidade the token of my other browser.

It is possible?

Comment: Have a look to [this](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-February/005131.html) thread.

Comment: Hi @Leonardo, have you found a solution of your problem? Have you followed the thread posted just above?

Comment: Hi, do you find anything better after 3 years? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

This feature has been implemented in keycloak version 17.
See: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10077

**Old workaround:**

Keycloak does not have this feature implemented yet. If you want you can create your own custom authenticator, for that you should have sound knowledge of keycloak codebase. I was facing the same issue and came up with a workaround.

Keycloak maintains active sessions of a user as shown below:
[image]

Every time a user logs in through different device, a session is added in the above list, we can use the above info to limit the user session to one.

I'm heavily making use of keycloak admin rest APIs to get the session-related data and to delete the session: [link here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/)

Make an API request to your server when a user logs in:

**client.js**

```
componentDidMount(){
      let auth = await keycloak.init({onLoad: "check-sso"});     
      if(auth){
         const {data} = await axios.get(`/check_session/${keycloak.subject}`);
         this.setState({isSessionValid: data.isSessionValid})
        }
      }

  render(){
    return(
      {this.state.isSessionValid ? 
        <YourComponent/> : 
        <div> You are already logged in!</div>
      }
    )
  }
```

**server.js**

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost/auth';
const realm = 'myRealm'

  // check session of user with same credentials from different devices
export const checkUserSession = async userId => {

    // initialize access token
    await initializeAccessToken(baseUrl); // check admin rest api docs of keycloak

    // get all active sessions of user
    const sessions = await getUserActiveSessions(baseUrl, realm, userId); // check admin rest api docs of keycloak

    // check if any session exists
    if (sessions && sessions.length > 1) {
      // sort with start time in descending order
      sessions.sort((a, b) => b.start - a.start);
      const currentSession = sessions[0]; // current logged in user's session
      const previousSession = sessions[1]; // previously active user's session
     
    /* I'm preventing current user to log in, for your case you can delete 
          the old session of this user here */   
     
     await deleteUserSession(baseUrl, realm, currentSession.id); // check admin rest api docs of keycloak
        return { isSessionValid: false, sessionData:previousSession };
    }
    // user logged in first time
    return { isSessionValid: true };
  };
```

Comment: I didn't find the API for deleting User Session, can you show the detail doc? Thanks!

Comment: @JeffTian Looks like they have implemented this feature in a newer version. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10077 .Also If you are looking for the API, go to the admin rest API doc and search for: DELETE /{realm}/sessions/{session}
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a lot of Keycloak users are interested in this feature so I am posting an answer which I found on my conducted research, this feature implemented by unofficial developer and here is what he shared

You can get the authenticators from my cloned branch:
https://github.com/mfdewit/keycloak/tree/KEYCLOAK-849-configurable-session-limits/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/sessionlimits

I've created 2 authenticators:

```
`RealmSessionLimitsAuthenticator`: limits the total number of sessions for a realm.
`UserSessionLimitsAuthenticator`: limits the number of session per user account and per client.
```

For now I advise you to copy them (including the factories) to your own project and make sure they are referenced in `META-INF/services`.
Also, change the `AuthenticationFlowError.SESSION_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` error to some value that exists in your Keycloak version. `SESSION_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` is added by me and only exists on my feature branch.

The downside is that you cannot provide the user proper feedback in case his session is denied.

If you have any questions on how these should be used, let me know!

Regarding the status of this task: I still have to write the integration tests before I can submit the merge request. But I'm planning to finish this soon. If anyone want to help writing these tests, I'd be grateful.

Still keycloak official JIRA i didn't find if they incorporated this feature in any recent version of Keycloak

[Source](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-849)

[https://github.com/mfdewit/keycloak/tree/KEYCLOAK-849-configurable-session-limits/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/sessionlimits](http://Source1)

Answer (score 1):

These feature has been implemented in keycloak 17 : https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10077

Answer (score 1):

**https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_admin/topics/authentication/flows.adoc**

[image]

Limits on the number of session that a user can have can be configured. Sessions can be limited per realm or per client.

To add session limits to a flow, perform the following steps.

Click Add step for the flow.

Select User session count limiter from the item list.

Click Add.

Click Required for the User Session Count Limiter authentication type to set its requirement to required.

Click ⚙️ (gear icon) for the User Session Count Limiter.

Enter an alias for this config.

Enter the required maximum number of sessions that a user can have in this realm. For example, if 2 is the value, 2 SSO sessions is the maximum that each user can have in this realm. If 0 is the value, this check is disabled.

Enter the required maximum number of sessions a user can have for the client. For example, if 2 is the value, then 2 SSO sessions is the maximum in this realm for each client. So when a user is trying to authenticate to client foo, but that user has already authenticated in 2 SSO sessions to client foo, either the authentication will be denied or an existing sessions will be killed based on the behavior configured. If a value of 0 is used, this check is disabled. If both session limits and client session limits are enabled, it makes sense to have client session limits to be always lower than session limits. The limit per client can never exceed the limit of all SSO sessions of this user.

Select the behavior that is required when the user tries to create a session after the limit is reached. Available behaviors are:

Deny new session - when a new session is requested and the session limit is reached, no new sessions can be created.

Terminate oldest session - when a new session is requested and the session limit has been reached, the oldest session will be removed and the new session created.

Optionally, add a custom error message to be displayed when the limit is reached.